# Complex matrix into real matrix

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

Can the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}e^{-it}&e^{-it}\\ie^{it}&-ie^{-it}\end{bmatrix}

be turned into the matrix 
\begin{bmatrix}\cos t&\sin t\\-\sin t&\cos t\end{bmatrix}

I tried taking the euler definition of cosine and sine and breaking the first matrix into its constituents of cosine and sine, yet I can't seem to get the second column since they have with them imaginary numbers as coefficients, and multiplying by $i$ will cause the equivalence to shatter. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what is that you mean when you talk about turning a matrix into another matrix, but if you are talking about *equivalent* matrices, then the answer is negative. If the were equivalent, then they would have the same traces. But the trace of the original matrix is not, in general, a real number, whereas the trace of the second matrix is *always* a real number.